# Upgrading GNOME

Tags: gnome, 17.10, gnome-shell

Is there a way to upgrade to GNOME `3.28` on Ubuntu 17.10? I'm experiencing the bug detailed [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/85), which has been fixed on version `3.28`. I am currently using version `3.26.2`.

Answer (score 0):

https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging?field.series_filter=artful

There you have gnome3 version 3.28 in 17.10

```
Also you can do-release-upgrade -d
```

To upgrade ubuntu to version 18.40